# Paint program trouble java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paint

I'm taking a Java course, this is my first computer science course.
The project I'm currently working on is a small Paint program I've put together so I can learn a bit of GUI programming (the course is actually all about algorithms).
I'm trying to change brush sizes (which I have labelled in my code). I can't get my head around just about how to do it though. In the meantime I will be working on it. Hopefully I can implement a menu :)

My file I/O I have also got partially to work however I'd like to focus on the brush size first.

A preview of what it does: http://youtu.be/Qgpol8_iKXQ

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PaintWindow frame = new PaintWindow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class PaintWindow extends JFrame {

    public PaintWindow() {
        setTitle(" Paint");
        setSize(700, 600);

        panel = new JPanel();
        drawPad = new PadDraw();

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 68));

//Creates a new container
        Container content = this.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

//sets the panel to the left, padDraw in the center (To the right of it)
        content.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);



//add the color buttons:
        makeColorButton(Color.MAGENTA);
        makeColorButton(Color.BLUE);
        makeColorButton(Color.CYAN);
        makeColorButton(Color.GREEN);
        makeColorButton(Color.YELLOW);
        makeColorButton(Color.ORANGE);
        makeColorButton(Color.RED);
        makeColorButton(Color.PINK);
        makeColorButton(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        makeColorButton(Color.GRAY);
        makeColorButton(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        makeColorButton(Color.BLACK);

//creates the eraser (Draws the background color which is white)
        JButton eraserButton = new JButton("Eraser");
        eraserButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPad.changeColor(Color.white);
            }
        });
        panel.add(eraserButton);

//creates the clear button
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPad.clear();
            }
        });
        panel.add(clearButton);

        JButton brush1Button = new JButton("Brush 1");
        brush1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//here
            }
        });
        panel.add(brush1Button);

        JButton brush2Button = new JButton("Brush 2");
        brush2Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//stuff here
            }
        });
        panel.add(brush2Button);

        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save As");
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPad.getWidth(), drawPad.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                //Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics(); 
                //drawPad.paint(graphics2D);
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:/.../Desktop/Example.png"));
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(saveButton);

    }


    /*
     * makes a button that changes the color
     * the color used for the button
     */
    public void makeColorButton(final Color color) {
        JButton tempButton = new JButton();
        tempButton.setBackground(color);
        tempButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        panel.add(tempButton);
        tempButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPad.changeColor(color);
            }
        });
    }
    private JPanel panel;
    private PadDraw drawPad;
}

class PadDraw extends JComponent {
//this is gonna be your image that you draw on
    Image image;
//this is what we'll be using to draw on
    Graphics2D graphics2D;
//these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates
    int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

    public PadDraw() {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
//if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
//coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates 
            //Thsi allows click and drag
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
//while the mouse is dragged it sets currentX & currentY as the mouses x and y
//then it draws a line at the coordinates
//it repaints it and sets oldX and oldY as currentX and currentY
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();

//draws a line
//graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);

//
//graphics2D.fillOval( (oldX-5), (oldY-5), 10, 10); 
//repaint();

//variable brush size here
                int nBsize;
                nBsize = 14;
                graphics2D.fillOval((oldX - (nBsize / 2)), (oldY - (nBsize / 2)), nBsize, nBsize);
                repaint();

                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
        });
    }

//this is the painting bit.
//if it has nothing on it then
//it creates an image the size of the window
//sets Graphics as the image
//sets the rendering
//then runs the clear() method
//then it draws the image
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics2D = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            clear();
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

//this is the clear
//it sets the color as white
//then it fills the window with white
//then it sets the color back to black
    public void clear() {
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }

    public void changeColor(Color theColor) {
        graphics2D.setPaint(theColor);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you want to post code please indent the lines by at least 4 spaces. This will display your code correctly with syntax highlighting. Better readability = Better answers.

Comment: It would be best if you could describe the intended result of your code, and what actually is happening.  It is a bit vague otherwise, if you just need more understanding of the issue.

Comment: I have created a static int variable stroke in PadDraw() class and then in the action of Bursh 1 and Bursh 2 i have changed its value and at the bottom i have added it to nBsize, now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See down how i did it**
I have created a static int variable `stroke` in `PadDraw()` class and then in the action of Bursh 1 and Bursh 2 i have changed its value and at the bottom i have added it to `nBsize`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PaintWindow frame = new PaintWindow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class PaintWindow extends JFrame {

    public PaintWindow() {
        setTitle(" Paint");
        setSize(700, 600);

        panel = new JPanel();
        drawPad = new PadDraw();

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 68));

//Creates a new container
        Container content = this.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

//sets the panel to the left, padDraw in the center (To the right of it)
        content.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);




//add the color buttons:
        makeColorButton(Color.MAGENTA);
        makeColorButton(Color.BLUE);
        makeColorButton(Color.CYAN);
        makeColorButton(Color.GREEN);
        makeColorButton(Color.YELLOW);
        makeColorButton(Color.ORANGE);
        makeColorButton(Color.RED);
        makeColorButton(Color.PINK);
        makeColorButton(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        makeColorButton(Color.GRAY);
        makeColorButton(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        makeColorButton(Color.BLACK);

//creates the eraser (Draws the background color which is white)
        JButton eraserButton = new JButton("Eraser");
        eraserButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPad.changeColor(Color.white);
            }
        });
        panel.add(eraserButton);

//creates the clear button
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPad.clear();
            }
        });
        panel.add(clearButton);

        JButton brush1Button = new JButton("Brush 1");
        brush1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//here     
                PadDraw.stroke = 10;
            }
        });
        panel.add(brush1Button);

        JButton brush2Button = new JButton("Brush 2");
        brush2Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PadDraw.stroke = 15;
//stuff here
            }
        });
        panel.add(brush2Button);

        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save As");
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPad.getWidth(), drawPad.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                //Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics(); 
                //drawPad.paint(graphics2D);
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:/.../Desktop/Example.png"));
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(saveButton);

    }


    /*
     * makes a button that changes the color
     * the color used for the button
     */
    public void makeColorButton(final Color color) {
        JButton tempButton = new JButton();
        tempButton.setBackground(color);
        tempButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        panel.add(tempButton);
        tempButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawPad.changeColor(color);
            }
        });
    }
    private JPanel panel;
    private PadDraw drawPad;
}

class PadDraw extends JComponent {
    //default value of stroke is 5
    static int stroke = 5;
//this is gonna be your image that you draw on
    Image image;
//this is what we'll be using to draw on
    Graphics2D graphics2D;
//these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates
    int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

    public PadDraw() {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
//if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
//coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates 
            //Thsi allows click and drag
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
//while the mouse is dragged it sets currentX & currentY as the mouses x and y
//then it draws a line at the coordinates
//it repaints it and sets oldX and oldY as currentX and currentY
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();

//draws a line
//graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);

//
//graphics2D.fillOval( (oldX-5), (oldY-5), 10, 10); 
//repaint();

//variable brush size here
                int nBsize;
                nBsize = stroke;

                graphics2D.fillOval((oldX - (nBsize / 2)), (oldY - (nBsize / 2)), nBsize, nBsize);
                repaint();

                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
        });
    }

//this is the painting bit.
//if it has nothing on it then
//it creates an image the size of the window
//sets Graphics as the image
//sets the rendering
//then runs the clear() method
//then it draws the image
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics2D = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            clear();
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

//this is the clear
//it sets the color as white
//then it fills the window with white
//then it sets the color back to black
    public void clear() {
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }

    public void changeColor(Color theColor) {
        graphics2D.setPaint(theColor);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the line marked with `// Bigger brush size`, you draw an oval that is always size 6 at the mouse position.  Then immediately after, your program draws a bigger oval on the same location.  This means that the first oval you drew gets erased right away.

To implement a variable-sized brush, you should use a variable (e.g. `int brushSize`) to keep track of the current size.  Then replace a line like:

```
graphics2D.fillOval( (oldX-3), (oldY-3), 6, 6);
```

with

```
graphics2D.fillOval((oldX-brushSize/2), (oldY-brushSize/2), brushSize, brushSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to draw from a method other than the `paintComponent` method will not work. What you need to do is have the `mouseXxxx` methods change class member coordinates that are also used in the `paintComponent` method, then call `repaint()`. Something like this

```
public class MyComp extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener{
    int x;
    int y;

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        x = p.getX();
        y = p.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

All you painting should go on in the `paintComponent` method. Use global variables that you use to paint , and just adjust those variables in other methods and call `repaint()`